# flutter listview listen to changes in file directory and rebuid the widget

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart

I'm building a download manager. How can listview widget listen to any changes such when download complete, the widget has to refresh automatically and when file is deleted the widget has to refresh automatically.

This is my code the secondtab which is responsible for download action once an action is fired from the first tab. The flutter_file_manager package is used fetch data in the directory. Share your thoughts on this?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:VideoTube/tabs/share.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_file_manager/flutter_file_manager.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SecondTab extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondTab({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondTabState createState() => _SecondTabState();
}

class _SecondTabState extends State<SecondTab> {
  var files;
  ShareModel share;

  _SecondTabState({this.share});

  void getFiles() async {
    //asyn function to get list of files
    //List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
    //var root = storageInfo[0].rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, geting the root directory
    var fm = FileManager(root: Directory('/storage/emulated/0/VideoTube/')); //
    files = await fm.filesTree(
        //set fm.dirsTree() for directory/folder tree list
        // excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/VideoTube/"],
        // extensions: ["mp4"] //optional, to filter files, remove to list all,
        //remove this if your are grabbing folder list
        );
    
    
    setState(() {}); //update the UI
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getFiles(); //call getFiles() function on initial state.
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("File/Folder list from SD Card"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Consumer<ShareProgress>(builder: (context, value, _) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                    width: 100.0,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    linearGradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
                    ),
                    lineHeight: 6.0,
                    percent: value.progress / 100,
                    center: Text(
                      "${value.progress}%",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 5.0),
                    ),
                    trailing: Icon(
                      Icons.mood,
                      size: 5,
                    ),
                    linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }

                // Container(
                //   child: Text('downloading.. ${value.progress}'),
                // ),
                ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              return Flexible(
                flex: 9,
                child: Container(
                  child: files == null
                      ? Text("Searching Files")
                      : ListView.builder(
                          //if file/folder list is grabbed, then show here
                          itemCount: files?.length ?? 0,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Card(
                                child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(files[index].path.split('/').last),
                              leading: Icon(Icons.video_label),
                              trailing: Icon(
                                Icons.delete,
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                              ),
                            ));
                          },
                        ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

This is how the UI looks like:

[image: This is how UI looks like]

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the FutureBuilder, if I have understood the problem correctly, the [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) may be the right solution, it listens for changes in a stream and rebuilds the child widgets with every change.